# Raspberry Pi Stop Motion Animation software

Tags: raspbian

I am looking for some suggestions on software to do Stop Motion Animation using a DSLR camera connected by USB. (I have already looked online but not found anything that meets my requirements)

Now I have found software for Windows and Mac and like the DragonFrame software using the trial it does exactly what I want plus loads more which I doubt I will ever use. but I don't like the price as this is just for me at home to make some lego animations.

I would like something that can 
1: Control the camera in taking the pictures and transferring them in (RAW, TIFF) format to a USB HDD or Drive.
2: Has an option to "onion skin" the images on the screen.
3: Has a simple interface which can be controlled by a keypad or keyboard

If anyone has any advice or knows of anything that could fulfill the requirements I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the Stopmotion software. Simply install it like this:

```
sudo apt-get install stopmotion
```

You can find tutorials on using this software online. There is even a blog article [describing the usage together with the Pi camera module](http://www.martymartin12.com/project52/2015/9/6/stop-motion-with-raspberry-pi).

The software also supports [DSLR cameras](http://linuxstopmotion.g-raffa.eu/configuration.html#dslr), albeit a bit experimental. I quote the section of the documentation:

> The tool for grabbing from DSLR cameras is gphoto. Install it with the
>   following terminal command:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install libgphoto2-2-dev
> ```
>
> Unfortunately gphoto has not all
>   the functionalities needed for a proper frame capture. For this reason
>   Herman Robak made up a small command line tool to make gphoto the
>   right tool for the task. It is called StubGrabber. As the name
>   suggests it is a prototype.
>
> Get the latest StubGrabber from our SourceForge repository with the
>   commands:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install git-core
> git clone git://git.code.sf.net/p/linuxstopmotion/fe09/code linuxstopmotion-fe09-code
> ```
>
> Compile it with the following terminal
>   commands:
>
> ```
> cd linuxstopmotion-fe09-code/stubgrabber gcc -o stubgrabber
> preview-capture.c -lgphoto2
> ```
>
> Now we can go back to Stopmotion
>   configuration window, Video import tab.
>
> Click on the Add button. A new line will be created. Double click in
>   the new Name text field. Type: gphoto. Double click in the new
>   Description text field. Type: StubGrabber for DSLR cameras Click on
>   the Edit button. If the text is not properly displayed, enlarge the
>   window by dragging its bottom border downwards. Leave the Pre-poll
>   command field blank. In the Start deamon text field copy and paste the
>   following command:
>
> ```
> /home/raffa/linuxstopmotion-fe09-code/stubgrabber/stubgrabber $IMAGEFILE &
> ```
>
> Adjust the path to the stubgrabber file to your case,
>   reflecting the location of the StubGrabber folder. In the Stop deamon
>   text field type:
>
> ```
> kill -9 $(pidof stubgrabber)
> ```
>
> Click on Apply and Close
>   the configuration window. Stopmotion is now ready to capture from your
>   camera.

Comment: WOW, ok ill have to try this then and see how it goes

Comment: @Arne there is a missing line break before the "git clone" which  is propably vital for copy-paste ;)

Comment: @flakeshake Fixed it.